# How do I turn references in Sequelize Auto to Associations in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use [Sequelize Auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) to generate my database definitions. Inside the definitions it defines which columns are foreign keys with the "references" property. However,

```
$ cat models/account.js
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('account', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    parent_account_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'account',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    master_account_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'account',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ''
    },
    enabled: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '1'
    },
    account_type_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false
    },
    billing_account_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'account',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    contact_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ''
    },
    contact_email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ''
    },
    data_feeds_path: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ''
    },
    requests: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '0'
    },
    true_impressions: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '0'
    },
    clicks: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '0'
    },
    actions: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '0'
    },
    conversions: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '0'
    },
    status_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '1',
      references: {
        model: 'status',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    status_modified_date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
    },
    date_created: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
    },
    date_created_user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '1',
      references: {
        model: 'user',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    date_modified: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
    },
    date_modified_user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '1',
      references: {
        model: 'user',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    date_deleted: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    date_deleted_user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'user',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'account'
  });
};
```

If I try to use joins in my Sequelize query, I receive:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: X is not associated to Y!
    at Model.validateIncludedElement (/Library/WebServer/adstudio/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:558:11)
    at /Library/WebServer/adstudio/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:440:29
    at Array.map (native)
    at Model.validateIncludedElements (/Library/WebServer/adstudio/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:436:37)
    at Model.aggregate (/Library/WebServer/adstudio/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1558:30)
    at Model.<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/adstudio/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1624:17)
    at runCallback (timers.js:666:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:639:5)
```

Here's the code that I've tried to use to add associations after importing the model definitions from my Sequelize Auto files:

```
        console.log("Length of models: " + Object.keys(instance.sequelize.models).length)
        for (var objectName in instance.sequelize.models) {
            var model = instance.sequelize.models[objectName];
            var columns = instance.sequelize.modelManager.getModel(model.name).attributes;
            console.log('Processing foreign keys for ' + model.name);
            for (var columnName in columns) {
                var column = columns[columnName];
                if (column.references) {
                    //if (column.references.key == column.references.model + '_id') {
                    if (model.name == column.references.model) {
                        console.log("  " + model.name + ' has one ' + column.fieldName.replace("_id", ""));
                        model.belongsTo(model, { as: column.fieldName.replace("_id", ""), foreignKey: column.fieldName });
                    } else {
                        //console.log(model.name + ' has one ' + column.references.model);
                        //console.log(column.references.model + ' has many ' + model.name);

                        // Will add foreignKey to the right-value table
                        //console.log("  " + model.name + " belongs to " + column.references.model + " on foreign key " + column.references.key);
                        //model.belongsTo(instance.sequelize.models[column.references.model], { foreignKey: column.references.key });

                        console.log("  " + column.references.model + " belongs to " + model.name + " on foreign key " + column.fieldName );
                        instance.sequelize.models[column.references.model].belongsTo(model, { foreignKey: column.fieldName });

                        console.log(model);

                        //model.hasOne(instance.sequelize.models[column.references.model]);
                        //instance.sequelize.models[column.references.model].hasMany(model);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I've tried just about every combination and the associations just don't define correctly, like saying that the account.id column is a foreign key for the account_audit_log table. I've tried just about every variation I can and can't see where it's possible.

Comment: have you found any solution for this mapping?

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't the self associations be defined as

```
Person.hasOne(Person, {as: 'Father'}) 
// this will add the attribute FatherId to Person
```

Though I haven't used sequelize auto